# Should I use the 'use' keyword in this code

Tags: rust

My code tree.

> src :
>
> ```
>  main.rs
>  modA    :
>            mod.rs
>            a.rs
> ```

main.rs :

```
mod modA;
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

mod.rs :

```
pub mod a;
```

a.rs : dummy function

This code compile.

But I have understood that I should write in mains.rs

> use mod modA

instead of

> mod modA

;
(as it indicated in this link :https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/use-declarations.html)
But the compilator has said :unresolved import.

Should I keep the code as he currently is or should I do otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not quite right, you should only use the `use` keyword to prevent having to type full path to items within the sub module in other modules outside main. To pull the submodule into the hierarchy, your first approach was correct:

```
mod modA
```